# Reading local json file - Ionic - working in broswer but not in actual device

Tags: json, ionic-framework

[Blank Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Urpnc.png)I am tying to fetch local JSON data using Ionic Angular. My files are as below.

Issue is i am able to view the app in browser, but when i install in mobile device, the nothing is displayed.

The page is blank. I believe there is some issue in JSON read using "fetch".

Can you pls suggest where I am going wrong?

My home.html looks like this as below:

```
<ion-header collapse="condense">
  <ion-navbar color="navbarColor">
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Home Exercise</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="itemTapped1($event, item)" no-lines text-wrap class="item">
      <ion-avatar item-start>
        <div>
          <img style="width: 15vh;height: 12vh;" src="{{item.icon1}}">
          
      </div>
      </ion-avatar>
      <h2>{{item.title1}}</h2>
      <p>Home Exercise</p>

    </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

My home.ts file looks like this as below:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-home-ionic',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})


export class HomePage {
  icon1: string[];
  title1: string[];
  items: any;
  dataurl : any = './assets/data/data.json';
  data: any;

  private readonly URL = './assets/data/data.json';
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,protected httpClient: HttpClient) {
    fetch(this.dataurl).then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {
      this.items = json;
    }); 
}
itemTap(event, data) {
  this.navCtrl.push(ItemPage, {
    data: data

  });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, your json file is embedded with your app, isn't it ?

Check that code in your angular.json:

```
   "assets": [
      {
        "glob": "**/*",
        "input": "src/assets",
        "output": "assets"
      },
...
```

If so, you should call your json with:

```
URL = "assets/data/data.json"
```

without the `./`

You use fetch and not httpClient.

You should modify your code to this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

  private readonly URL = 'assets/data/data.json';
  items: any[];

  constructor(public httpClient: HttpClient) {
    this.httpClient.get(this.URL)
      .subscribe((res: any) => {
        this.items = res;
        console.warn(this.items);
      });
  }

}
```

The console displays this result:

[image]

Comment: I tried using what you suggested but still not working. I have attached the image of the actual app when installed in device.

Comment: Can you provide what should be written inside .subscribe(res => {   }); ?

Comment: I updated my answer with the code inside subscribe.
Supposing your json file is an array like [
{"name":"hello"},
{"name":"world!"}
]
I checked in real app, it works perfectly.
Don't forget to check the answer if it works for you too.